# How do I roll when a weapon has multiple different damage types?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, damage-types

So I've been out of 5e for years and I'm recently getting back into it and I had a question about one of my weapons. It's a sword that does 2d6 piercing and 1d6 force. Do just roll 3d6, or do I do separate rolls?

Comment: Hi and welcome!  You may have accidentally created two accounts-- post on [meta] to have them merged.  Also see the [help] when you have some time, and the [tour] if you aren't also @Medix2

Answer (score 21):

## Mostly 3d6

The large majority of monsters do not care about force damage either way, and the sword *must* be magical if it has this special power.

### Few exceptions

Against monsters that have resistance or vulnerability to *force*, but not *slashing*<sup>1</sup>, (or the other way around), you have to roll separately.

*Swarms* for example resist slashing damage even from magical sources:

- 1d6 is not halved
- 2d6 (plus your Str or Dex modifier, and whatever else you add) is halved

### Solution

Always roll the *force* 1d6 with a dice of a different color, but tell your DM the total result, and mention that X of it is force, while Y is magic slashing.
As stated above, most of the time he will not care, and you do not want to make his job unnecessarily harder. If he cares, he will let you know.

---

1) Or *piercing*, or whatever kind of damage the base sword does.

Comment: I'd argue you should always roll different colored dice, and report it separated out -- because only the DM should know if the creature has resistance or immunity.  If the DM is nice He'll hint at it after the first attack of that type.

Comment: @J.A.Streich this is what I meant, I rephrased

Comment: I always report the damage of my warlock with *hex* and a psychic-damage sword as “*X* psychic damage, *Y* necrotic damage, *X* + *Y* total.” I don’t see how that is making my DM’s job harder if the extra information is extraneous. I don’t know that I think it’s a good suggestion to add things up without saying.

Comment: @KRyan I meant most of the time (99% in this case) he only needs the total, providing 3 number will make thing more confusing. He has to keep in mind enough things as it is.